# When finding an object, how to order its fetched children objects by fields in their table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

Lets say have a booking system for booking a time slot for a certain event.

I have an events model and a time_slot model. Each event has man time_slots, and each slot belongs to an event

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :time_slot
end

class TimeSlot < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end
```

When I do an `Event.find(some_id)`
how do I order the time slots returned based on a field on their model eg 'slot_time'

Comment: Be nice to your fellow programmers and use the proper plural `has_many :time_slots`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like this:

```
Event.find(some_id).time_slot.order(:slot_time)
```

`time_slot` doesn't actually return all associated time slots, it returns an ActiveRecord::Relation, just like `TimeSlot.where(booked: true)` would. Therefore you can just chain more query methods to this relation.